# Using the Aurelia <content> element

Tags: aurelia, custom-element

I'm trying to create a custom element that allows the user to specify the element's content when creating the element, like this:

```html
<custom-element title="Hello">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</custom-element>
```

And my custom element essentially looks like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="my-custom-element">
        <h2 if.bind="title">${title}</h2>
        <content></content>
    </div>
</template>
```

I've totally guessed at the use of the `<content>` element and it doesn't work like this it seems. I can't find any documentation on it either. I've seen others use it with a `select` attribute pointing to a specific element *inside* the custom element's contents but I want to access everything inside it - not a particular element.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aurelia uses `<slot>` element to render content within custom elements. You can read about it in [documentation hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/6), or take a look at [blog post](http://blog.durandal.io/2016/05/23/aurelia-shadow-dom-v1-slots-prerelease/) where they explain the reasoning for `<slot>` elements. Basically, it's a part of [Shadow DOM v1 specification](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/) and Aurelia team tries to follow the standards wherever possible.

One cool thing with `<slot>` is that you can have multiple named ones in your custom element, which is explained in post above.

So, your custom element would look something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="my-custom-element">
        <h2 if.bind="title">${title}</h2>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Of course, this means that you'll need to use the newer version of Aurelia, since this has been added sometime at the end of May.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Not sure where I got the `<content>` element from? But I've definitely seen it in tutorials.

Comment: They were using `<content>` before, but went with Shadow DOM standard once it's published. There are still some old posts mentioning `<content>`.